# swift ios check for iphone 5 or iphone 6 using size class portrait mode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, size-classes

I wonder if its possible to check if the user is using an iphone 5 or iphone 6 using size class?

I have a header image that I want to make larger when the user is using an iphone 6 instead of iphone 5.

Right now I am using [this](https://github.com/dennisweissmann/DeviceKit) library to check what device.

And I do so by adding this in `viewDidLoad`

```
if device == .iPhone5 || device == .iPhone5s || device == .iPhone5c {
    //Update image size constraints etc
   view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

But is it possible to use size class only?

Comment: I cant find any portrait size class to check if iphone 6 or iphone 5 : /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only iphone 6 plus has different size class (regular class at landscape). You can't distinguish between iphone 5 and 6 using size class.

You can use **viewWillTransitionToSize** and check screen size to determine the device.  Alternatively, you can use the following variables:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width
```

([SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4614966/1586231))
In instances where two devices with equal screen sizes but different resolutions exist, the [scaling factor of resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14004085/1586231) could be used to discern which device you're dealing with. ([DOCS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html))

```
float scaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```